# Android beginner button

Tags: android, button, onclick

trying to move to a new activity and pass a different variable depending on what button has been pressed, so far the code I have is

```
 public void onClickker(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.answer1: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("answer", 1);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.answer2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            intent2.putExtra("answer", 1);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.answer3:

            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            intent3.putExtra("answer", 1);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;

        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
    }
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onClickker(v);
        }
    });

    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickker(v);
        }
    });

    Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickker(v);
        }
    });
```

Unforunately, whenever I press any of the buttons nothing happens? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks guy :)

Comment: Also, I know the putExtra each puts the value 1, I will change this in a minute, but it's not the issue i'm having with my code. Thanks guys.

Comment: What will happen if you remove `finish()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are you initializing your buttons and attaching the listener. according the code you've posted your buttons have been initialized in the onclickker method. They should be initialized in onCreate() or a function called from onCreate().

Comment: That might be the problem. I'm a complete beginner here.  I added them to the xml file and they appeared, so I assumed they had been created because they're appearing on the screen?

Comment: go to your onCreate() function in the activity and paste button initialization code there

Comment: `Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onClickker(v);
        }
    });`  write the respective code for all 3 buttons in onCreate()

Comment: Thanks, the rest of the code worked fine ( not saying it was the best practice) and after adding the buttons to onCreate() it works fine. Thanks a lot guys :D

Answer (score 0):

When start a activity,don't use application context,
for example,replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
```

Comment: The problem relates to the IDE telling me that onClickker is never used?

Comment: If you add log in OnClickker,it will be print?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `case` is wrong formatted and you can create `Intent` object only once for every `case`

Click Method

```
public void onClickker(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.b1: 
        intent.putExtra("answer", 1);
        break;
    ....
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
        break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

button listener :

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClickker(v);
    }
});
```